# A mini max game search tree gives error: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, minimax

I'd like to perform Mini-Max algorithm on 2048 game. In order to do so, I've first created a tree

```
class Tree(object):
def __init__(self, num_sons, data,  parent=None):
    self.data = [None, data]
    self.sons = []
    self.index_son = 0
    self.parent = parent
    for i in range(num_sons):
        self.sons.append(None)

def add_son(self, son):
    self.sons[self.index_son] = son
    self.index_son += 1

def get_son(self, index):
    return self.sons[index]

def is_terminal(self):
    return self.index_son == 0
```

Basically every node has a different number of offsprings for every action possible. Actions of Max are the usual actions in the game of 2048, moving right up down or left and Actions of Min are the actions of creating additional 2's blocks in the game (whenever you don't make progress in 2048 there are additional 2's block created on the edges).

I've created the tree so the terminals hold the values.
Now I want to use the MiniMax algorithm to have the data initialized in every node of the tree.

Trying to this:

```
    def minimax(self, root, player_turn):
    if root.is_terminal():
        return root.data[1]
    else:
        if player_turn % 2 == 0:
            for i in range(root.index_son):
                root.data[1] = max(root.data[1], self.minimax(root.get_son(i), 1))
        if player_turn % 2 == 1:
            for i in range(root.index_son):
                root.data[1] = min(root.data[1], self.minimax(root.get_son(i), 0))
```

And I get an error

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'float'
```

On this line:

```
root.data[1] = max(root.data[1], self.minimax(root.get_son(i), 1))
```

I know I don't return anything if node isn't a terminal but I don't know what to add in those cases.

Comment: Well yeah, you don't return anything if the node isn't terminal.

Comment: I know that, but I've no idea of how to fix it

Comment: Just return something from the function.

Comment: would return root.data[1] on the end of the else be sufficient ?

Comment: If that's what you want it to return, then yes.